# Insert a value containing single quotes in javascript

Tags: javascript

```
document.execCommand('insertHTML', false, 'Hello this is Veena's message');
```

How can i insert text which contains a single quotes other than passing it in double quotes like

```
document.execCommand('insertHTML', false, "Hello this is Veena's message");
```

Answer (score 2):

As with nearly every other language with a similar syntax (B, C, C++, C#, Java, ...), you can escape the `'` with a backslash:

```
document.execCommand('insertHTML', false, 'Hello this is Veena\'s message');
```

Answer (score 2):

You should escape the single quotes with \

Answer (score 1):

Escape the quotes:

```
document.execCommand('insertHTML', false, 'Hello this is Veena\'s message');
```

More info : http://www.quackit.com/javascript/tutorial/javascript_escape_characters.cfm

Another option, is using the html character code for it.

```
document.write('veena&#39s');
```

Comment: currently my string is saved in a variable in android. I will be sending this variable to document.execCommand. Before sending this variable i have to call String.replaceall("'","\'"); which is not working for me. That is why i posted the question. Is there any way to replace single quotes with escape sequence

Answer (score 1):

```
document.execCommand('insertHTML', false, 'Hello this is Veena\'s message');
```

Use the backslash before it. and this will work.

Answer (score 1):

Escape the Quote:

```
'Hello this is Veena\'s message'
```